# Teacher of the Pnei Yehoshua

Tags: rabbis, commentaries, acharonim, yekke

What was the name of the rav/teacher of HoRav Ya'akov Yehoshua ben Tzvi, author of the Pnei Yehoshua?

Comment: Did you check wikipedia? https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%A7

Comment: @DoubleAA I did, but I found no answer to this question

Comment: Does this line help you? "למד תורה אצל רבותיו, תחילה בבית דודו שמואל, ולאחר מכן בקרקוב ובבובה אצל הרב חיים רייצעס."